# Hibernate throws "Repeated column in mapping for entity" when using OrderColumn with two lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a tricky problem to let hibernate order two list of the same entity. With some code it could be easier to understand what I wanna do.

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract class AbstractParent { 
    List<CommonObject> commonObjects;

    public abstract List<CommonObject> getCommonObjects(); 
}

@Entity 
@Table 
public class Child1 extends AbstractParent {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="child1_id", nullable = false) 
    @OrderColumn(name = "sort_index") 
    public List<CommonObject> getCommonObject() { 
       return this.commonObjects; 
    } 
}

@Entity 
@Table 
public class Child2 extends AbstractParent {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="child2_id", nullable = false) 
    @OrderColumn(name = "sort_index") 
     public List<CommonObject> getCommonObject() { 
         return this.commonObjects; 
     } 
}
```

But because hibernate handle the mapping of the column "sort_index", it's mapped twice (for Child1 and Child2). So I get this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity ... column: sort_index (should be mapped with
>   insert="false" update="false")

I know that I can resolve this problem if I put two different columns for sorting. But I would like to know if someone has a better solution to give me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a test to replicate your issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/inheritance/SortIndexCollectionInheritance.java) and it works after modifying the mappings to this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractParent {
    public abstract List<CommonObject> getCommonObjects();
}

@Entity(name = "Child1")
public class Child1 extends AbstractParent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CommonObject.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "child_1_common_objects", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="child1_id", nullable = false))
    @OrderColumn(name = "sort_index")
    private List<CommonObject> commonObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<CommonObject> getCommonObjects() {
        return this.commonObjects;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Child2")
public class Child2 extends AbstractParent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CommonObject.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "child_2_common_objects", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="child2_id", nullable = false))
    @OrderColumn(name = "sort_index")
    private List<CommonObject> commonObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<CommonObject> getCommonObjects() {
        return this.commonObjects;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "CommonObject")
public class CommonObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand well, I need two other tables which join my Child1 and Child2 objects to CommonObject ?

Comment: I haven't tried with the same table, but you can give it a try and see if it works.